# Positioning text on top of the picture

Tags: html, css

Problem:
I am having problem with positioning text right in the middle of the picture that has fullwidth.

Currently it is kinda good but not on every resolution.

My code:
      [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hobtjadj/)

I'm trying to achieve this with

```
.title{
    position:absolute;
    left: -140px;
    top: 100px;
}
```

I've tried using % for `left` and `top` but it still moves around.

Try changing that result area and you will see that text is moving and I don't want that.

What I want is that `h2` and `h6` to be in the middle of that picture no matter which resolution is used.

How can I solve this?

Thank you.

Comment: `middle`... Xmiddle-Ymiddle or Xleft-Ymiddle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this way:

```
.titles {
    color: white !important;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
}
```

#### Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/praveenscience/c5f3bufq/

Comment: Thank you. Is it possible to do it without that text-align center?

Comment: Why don't you need `text-align: center`?

Comment: Because if I add background to that text and depends on the page but if the text is larger then I should split it in two lines.

Answer (score 0):

Use the property relative that you wont have problems.

```
.titles {
    color: white !important;
    left: 75px;
    position: relative;
    top: 150px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That can be done easier. You can put the title in a single div, img doesn't need to be in a div. Then just align the text in the center. I've even added the vertical center logic:

```
.title h2 { 
    position: relative;
    /* Vertical center */
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    /* prefixes needed for cross-browser support */
    -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);

    /* Horizontal center  */
    text-align: center;

    /* Push it up a little, to position it nicely in the image */
    margin-top: -1em; 
}
```

**[Full JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hobtjadj/3/)**

Answer (score 0):

```css
.titles{position:relative;}
.text h2,
.text h6{
    color: #fff;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 2px;
}
.text{
    position:absolute;
    text-align:center; /* or use left:10%; ?*/
    top:42%;
    width:100%;
}
.titles img{ width:100%;}
```

```html
<div class="titles">
    <img src="http://i62.tinypic.com/4sz2gx.jpg"/>
    <div class="text">
        <h2>Lorem, dolorem</h2>
        <h6>Lorem dolorem lorem dolorem</h6>
    </div>
</div>
```